# "Where" as a conjunction

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

There were two sentences I wrote:

1. We did a science experiment where we dissected frogs.
2. This is the last day where I'll be waiting for you by your locker.

I'm not sure if *where* can be used as a conjunction... I've been using it as a conjunction, but this is the first time I've actually noticed it.

If using *where* as a conjunction (in the form I wrote as above), would it be grammatically correct? If so, please explain why. Why can *where* be a conjunction if the word means location? And, what do you have to put a comma before *where* **if** it can be used as a conjunction?

Answer (score 2):

Where is a relative adverbial pronoun of location, and relative pronouns can introduce relative clauses. Normally, it refers back to a location; however, the place–time [conceptual metaphor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_metaphor) is extremely common in Indo-European languages, and *where* can also be used to refer to a time or occasion. It is correctly so used in your first example, as in *we dissected frogs in this experiment*, where *in* uses the same conceptual metaphor of place for time. But it does sound a little bit informal.

In your second example, *where* is slightly less normal, probably because (elliptical) *that* is normally used after specific words indicating a time, such as *day, moment, year,* etc. I think *that* or a void is certainly preferable to your *where*, but it is probably acceptable. You can usually use *where* in sentences where you could replace it with *in which* or *at which*, but that is not possible here.

As to the comma, I would say the same rules apply as to other relative clauses: use a comma with non-defining relative clauses, but no comma with defining ones.

Answer (score 1):

'Where' is correct in example 1, but not needed in 2) as the locker is the location. All that's needed for that is to say "...last day I'll be waiting...'

Comment: "Where" is not correct in either case. It is not a conjunction, but a preposition which provides identification of a location. So you could say, "This is the lake where I will be waiting for you." In your two examples, you have "where" referring to an activity (science experiment) and a segment of time ("last day"). The experiment would properly be identified by "in which." But, Amanda, "where" in the second example does not refer to the locker; it is structured to refer to the "last day," which is incorrect.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg *Where* is not a preposition. It is either a subordinating conjunction, or a "relative adverb" introducing an adjective clause, in both cases. It's the wrong one in (2) -- that should be *when* because it's explicitly dealing with time.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: *When*, really? I'm not sure I agree...

Comment: @AndrewLeach You're oorrect. I can't edit the comment at this point, however, so I'll say IGNORE THAT ERROR; delete sentence number two. The rest of my comment stands.

Comment: @Cerberus [Your own second paragraph](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/107254/18696) explains why *where* is not suited; *when* is (for *on which* in your constructions)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: *This is the last day when I'll be waiting for you by your locker.* — I'm sorry, but that doesn't sound right to me...it's hard to say why. Perhaps because *when* is not used for a period of time, and *the last day* refers to a period (every day up to and including this day)? Or just because *that* / void exerts so much pressure? I would definitely say *This is the last day (that) I'll be waiting for you by your locker.*

Comment: @Cerberus Perhaps it's a BrE thing. It certainly doesn't wrong to me.

Comment: Would it be formal to include "where" in sentence number one?

Answer (score 0):

In (1), 'where' is a conjunction, just as saying 'We did a science experiment **after** we dissected frogs.'

(2) is wrong.

Comment: (Further to what I just said): In (1) 'where' is not a relative pronoun because it stands for 'in that place' and not 'that place'. A pronoun has to take the place of a noun.  'where' is also not a preposition because it does not describe the relation between two enitities - it does not have an object.

Answer (score -1):

Where as a conjunction is acceptable in informal writing and communication (it is considered 'non-standard'). So if you are writing an informal letter or email, both examples are fine. However, if you are writing something formal, both examples would have to be revised.

Comment: And no commas are needed in either if used informally and kept as is.